# Nodejs Child Process with Unix Executable

Tags: node.js, executable

I'm having a problem with the 'child_process' module and an executable program. I want to pipe the stdout from the executable to my node process.

I have no problem getting this to work with simple commands such as "cat" and "ls" but not with my executable. I'm using the code below.

My executable logs data to the terminal when run standalone so I'm not sure why this isn't working. The node script and executable are in the same directory and running on MacOS X.

EDIT: The executable remains running permanently once started.

```
var cp = require('child_process');

var cat = cp.spawn('cat', ['udpServer.js']);
cat.stdout.on('data', function(m) {
  // This will log just fine!
  console.log('cat');
  console.log(m);
});

var tracker = cp.spawn('./MyExecutable', []);
tracker.stdout.on('data', function(data){
  // This is never logged
  console.log('MyExecutable');
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: have you tried removing first spawn and leaving only "./MyExecutable"?

Comment: also, update your executable to log if it's being launched.

Comment: Thanks jancha, my executable logs when it's launched to stdout and after it finishes setting up it will log it's output continuously to stdout.

Comment: I originally didn't have the first spawn, but put it in as a sanity check and just left it here in the post to clarify other processes worked for me.

Comment: This worked fine for me on Ubuntu.  What does MyExecutable do?  Could it be waiting for user input or some event?

Comment: Hmm I'll take a look again Jonathan. The process is detecting input from a camera and tracking body joints, similar to Kinect for XBox. The software is using "NITE2 MIDDLEWARE WITH OPENNI2" or so I'm told, I have just written this node process to try and trap the data being streamed from stdout of this software and send it over a socket for a friend.

When MyExecutable is run by itself it is working just fine and streaming data to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct path to your executable command. To be sure I like to specify absolute paths when spawning commands that are not in the node process `$PATH` variable

```
var inspect = require('eyespect').inspector();
var path = require('path')
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
var cmd = path.join(__dirname, 'MyExecutable')
inspect(cmd, 'command to spawn')
var args = []
var tracker = spawn(cmd, args)
tracker.stdout.setEncoding('utf8')
tracker.stderr.setEncoding('utf8')
tracker.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  inspect('stdout data')
  console.log(data)
})
tracker.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  inspect('stderr data')
  console.log(data)
})
```