# node.js does not respect all paths in $PATH variable

Tags: node.js, child-process

This question is related to 
[Nodejs Child Process with Unix Executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104647/nodejs-child-process-with-unix-executable).

However I could not find a good solution and thanks to my reputation points, I am unable to post a comment there.

To explain my problem, I have some of my own executables which I need to execute from node.js. The path for these executables is already set in the PATH variable. Hence, I can run my executables without any path-prefix from Terminal.

Inspite of that, node.js receives **process.env.PATH** set to following value:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

I tried appending the path to it before spawning the process:

```
process.env.PATH = process.env.PATH + ":<path_to_my_executables>"
```

but the process exits with 127 Shell code which is "command not found" if I correctly remember.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It should work fine with `.spawn()`. Though, `.exec()` by default ignores your `process.env` and executes command in an empty environment.

Comment: By the way, why can't you provide a full path to your executable spawning a child process?

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny: Thank you for your prompt reply. I tried using absolute path to my executable but that fails too. Apparently it needs Java and some more executables which are set on the PATH variable.

Is there any way to make node.js use the correct PATH variable values?

Comment: Are you sure that your script have executable flag?

Comment: Oh yes! It has 'x' bit set for all users.

Comment: Do you have whitespaces in your path (including script filename)?

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny> No, the names are really small without any special characters. I just posted a workaround as an answer below. Please have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got it work using a shell script. Definitely there must be a better solution to this.

I exported the required paths to my executable (and its dependencies) in the shell script first and then started execution. Hence the shell script structure is something like:

```
export JAVA_HOME=<java_path>
export EXECUTABLES_HOME=<executables_path>
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$EXECUTABLES_HOME"
<execute_required_executable> <arguments>
```

If someone has a better solution, please do let me know!